# List appending weird error: python

Tags: python, numpy

here is the gist of the problem. If you want then you can read the code.

I am appending two numpy array list to one..by following command:

```
np.append(list1,list2)
```

What i am expecting is that output list to be of length of len(list1) + len(list2)
But instead the output is entirely of different length.
The code is down.. Its bit long..sorry about that. 
Are there any "gotchas" for such kind of appending operations?
Thanks

I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong??Let me just write the code and the out put..and what i was expecting and what i am getting :(
Also read the output.. I have highlighted where the error is

```
So I input two list and their corresponding labels.
import numpy as np
def list_appending( list_1, list_2,  y_one, y_two):
 count_1 = len(list_1)
 count_2 = len(list_2)
  #if one list is bigger than other.. then add synthetic values shorter list 
   #and its target y variable
 if count_1 > count_2:

    diff = count_1 - count_2
    new_y = np.zeros(diff)
    new_feature_list = generate_synthetic_data(list_2,diff)

    print "appended ", len(new_feature_list)," synthetic entries to first class (label0)"
elif count_2 > count_1:
    diff = count_2 - count_1
    new_feature_list = generate_synthetic_data(list_1,diff)
    new_y = np.ones(diff)
    print "appended ", len(new_feature_list)," synthetic entries to second class (label1)"
else:
    diff = 0
    new_feature_list = []
    print "nothing appended"
print "class 1 y x",len(y_one), len(list_1)
print "class 2 y x",len(y_two), len(list_2)

print "len l1 l2 ",len(list_1) , len(list_2)
f_list = np.append(list_1,list_2) # error is in this line.. unexpected.. see output
print "first x append ", len(f_list)
f_list = np.append(f_list,new_feature_list)
print "second x append ", len(f_list)
print "new features ", len(new_y), len(new_feature_list)
new_y_list =  np.append(y_one,y_two)
print "first y append ", len(new_y_list)
new_y_list = np.append(new_y_list,new_y)
print "second y append ", len(new_y_list)
# print features_list_1.shape, features_list_2.shape, new_feature_list.shapes
#print len(features_list_1[0]), len(features_list_2[0]), len(new_feature_list[0])


print "appended ", len(f_list), len(new_y_list)
return f_list, new_y_list
```

Output:

```
appended  35839  synthetic entries to first class (label0)
class 1 y x 42862 42862
class 2 y x 7023 7023
len l1 l2  42862 7023
first x append  349195 <----- This is the error line 42862 + 7023 = 49885
second x append  600068
 new features  35839 35839
first y append  49885   <------------This append was just fine..
second y append  85724
appended  600068 85724
```

Comment: @Fraz my guess on your downvote(s): an excessively long code block (boil it down to a simple example), awful formatting and spelling ("adn teh out put") and a general _solve my problem_ for me without effort on your part. Put time into your question and we'll put time in our answers.

Comment: @above: i have really looked into the code for awful time before posting it here ( to answer that i didnt put any effort) but anyways.. i have mentioned the gist..

Comment: I actually figured that out..Its a multidimensional array.. So append flattens the multidimensional array into 1 big list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html?highlight=append#numpy.append):

```
If axis is None, out is a flattened array.
```

My guess is that you did not want to flatten the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very very hard to understand.

As I see it, you have two lists -- `list1` and `list2` -- and you want to pad the shorter one to make them the same length. To do that neatly:

```
n, m = len(list1), len(list2)

if n > m:
    # Make the shorter list come first
    list1, list2 = list2, list1
    n, m = m, n

list1.append(generate_padding(m-n) if n < m else [])
```